# omnipay package guzzle/common is abandon

Tags: omnipay

When I installed omnipay through composer I got the following errors. Are there any plans to use the latest version of Guzzle?

```
Package guzzle/common is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzle/guzzle instead.
Package guzzle/stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzle/guzzle instead.
Package guzzle/parser is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzle/guzzle instead.
Package guzzle/http is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzle/guzzle instead.
Package guzzle/plugin-mock is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzle/guzzle instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Omnipay V3 will use Guzzle 5.0, rather than Guzzle 3. It was discussed here: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/235